# if filename then move file

Tags: bash, if-statement, filenames

I am use a if command if filename then move file

this is what I have so far

```
filename=$*test*
if [ -f "filename" ]
then
  mv filename archive/filename
else
  echo "no filename exists"
fi
```

When I run the script I get "no filename exists"

How can I use a wildcard as a variable?

Comment: What language is this? Please add the appropriate tag to your question. What do you expect `$*test*` to be?

Comment: This is bash. I am looking for test to be a wild card for a part of a filename

Answer (score 0):

Your script has several problems.

```
filename=$*test*
```

`$*test*` is not valid bash syntax. The `$` indicates a variable.

> I am looking for test to be a wild card for a part of a filename

If that is the case, you need to drop the leading `$`. Or possibly what you meant was `*${test}*`.

```
mv filename archive/filename
```

This would move a file named "filename", which is likely not what you want. You probably want:

```
mv "$filename" archive/
```

If you are not renaming the file, you do not need to specify the name in the target.

If you change this line:

```
echo "no filename exists"
```

to:

```
echo "no $filename exists"
```

Include the dollar sign and you will see exactly what file the script tried to look for.

Some additional notes:

- Include `set -x` at the start of your script. This will show you each command expanded so you can see what is actually happening.
- Have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/ which can pick up a lot of syntax errors.